# hapi.js best way to handle errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, hapi.js

I'm creating my first node.js REST web service using hapi.js. I'm curious as to the best way to handle errors let's say from my dao layer. Do i `throw` them in my dao layer and then just `try/catch` blocks to handle them and send back errors in my controller, or is there a better way that the cool kids are handling this?

routes/task.js

```
var taskController = require('../controllers/task');
//var taskValidate = require('../validate/task');

module.exports = function() {
  return [
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/tasks/{id}',
      config : {
        handler: taskController.createTask//,
        //validate : taskValidate.blah
      }
    }
  ]
}();
```

controllers/task.js

```
var taskDao = require('../dao/task');

module.exports = function() {

  return {

    /**
     * Creates a task
     *
     * @param req
     * @param reply
     */
    createTask: function createTask(req, reply) {

      taskDao.createTask(req.payload, function (err, data) {

        // TODO: Properly handle errors in hapi
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        reply(data);
      });

    }
}();
```

dao/task.js

```
module.exports = function() {

  return {
    createTask: function createTask(payload, callback) {

    ... Something here which creates the err variable...

    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // How to properly handle this bad boy
    }
  }
}();
```

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on what the error is, regardless of the framework involved.  If it's something the user did wrong, then we can notify them (4XX type error), otherwise it's our fault so let them know (5XX type error). Hapi does come bundled with [boom](https://github.com/spumko/boom) which you can use to return errors to your clients.  Another solution within this area is [good](https://github.com/spumko/good), which can help with monitoring your process for errors, logs, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In doing more research along with *Ricardo Barros*' comment on using [Boom](https://github.com/spumko/boom), here's what I ended up with.

`controllers/task.js`

```
var taskDao = require('../dao/task');

module.exports = function() {

  return {

    /**
     * Creates a task
     *
     * @param req
     * @param reply
     */
    createTask: function createTask(req, reply) {

      taskDao.createTask(req.payload, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
          return reply(Boom.badImplementation(err));
        }

        return reply(data);
      });

    }
}();
```

`dao/task.js`

```
module.exports = function() {

  return {
    createTask: function createTask(payload, callback) {

    //.. Something here which creates the variables err and myData ...

    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    //... If successful ...
    callback(null, myData);
  }
}();
```

Comment: you have a bug in there:
```javascript
reply(Boom.badImplementation(err));
```

needs a return, like return reply(...)

Answer (score 9):

## Generic Solution w/ *Fully Customisable* Error Template/Messages

We wrote a Hapi Plugin that handles all errors seamlessly: [npmjs.com/package/**hapi-error**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-error)

[image: Build Status]
[image: codecov.io]
[image: Code Climate]
[image: Dependency Status]

It lets you define your own custom error pages in 3 easy steps.

#### 1. Install the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-error) from npm:

```
npm install hapi-error --save
```

#### 2. Include the plugin in your Hapi project

Include the plugin when you `register` your server:

```
server.register([require('hapi-error'), require('vision')], function (err) {
 // your server code here ...
});
```

> See: [/example/server_example.js](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-error/blob/master/example/server_example.js) for simple example

#### 3. Ensure that you have a View called `error_template`

> Note: `hapi-error` plugin *expects* you are using [`Vision`](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) (*the standard view rendering library for Hapi apps*)
>   which allows you to use **Handlebars**, Jade, ***React***, *etc*. for your templates.

Your `error_template.html` (*or `error_template.ext` `error_template.jsx`*) should make use of the 3 variables it will be passed:

- `errorTitle` - *the error tile generated by Hapi*
- `statusCode` - *HTTP statusCode sent to the client *e.g: `404`* (*not found*)
- `errorMessage` - the *human-friendly error message*

> for an example see: [`/example/error_template.html`](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-error/blob/master/example/error_template.html)

*That's it*! Now your Hapi App handles all types of errors and you can throw your own custom ones too!

[image: hapi-error-screens]

> Note: `hapi-error` works for REST/APIs too. if the content type header (`headers.acceps`) is set to `application/json` then your app will return a JSON error to the client, otherwise an HTML page will be served.

Answer (score 3):

I think the cool kids now use a package to caught unhandled errors with Hapi, I present to you, [Poop](https://github.com/spumko/poop).

The only thing Poop is missing is some rich documentation, but check it out, and you'll see that Poop is great.

Some of my friends went to a node.js event in Lisbon, on of the hosts was a guy in charge of web technology stack at Wallmart, they use Hapi.js, Poop and some other cool things.

So if they use poop it must be pretty awesome.

*PS: The name is suppa awesome*

Comment: Cool kids are using poop? Man i'm way out of the loop....From my understanding Poop is only for uncaught exceptions. I think you still need to handle exceptions as best as you can though so that you return the appropriate response, but I just wasn't sure if try/catch was still the way to go.

Comment: Do you care about this errors ? or can you just dump them in the log and continue to serve your awesome content ? If you answer this two questions yes, you can use poop, or you can use cluster module and fork the process every times it "dies", but I wouldn't use this if you except to have a lot of unhandled errors. Take in mind you need to use a error handler or create one, to give a pretty answer to the user